# Why is this returning an error?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, eval, instance

```
BasicObject.class_eval do
    def instance(ins)
        eval "@#{ins}=#{ins}", binding
    end
end
```

Is the code in question. What I want it to do is in the following code, create a new instance variable, bar, inside class Foo.
What I get after running this code:

```
class Foo
  bar = 3
end
Foo.instance(:bar)
```

is:

```
 NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar for Foo:Class
        from /Users/Solomon/Desktop/Ruby/instance.rb:3:in `instance'
        from /Users/Solomon/Desktop/Ruby/instance.rb:3:in `eval'
        from /Users/Solomon/Desktop/Ruby/instance.rb:3:in `instance'
```

Why is this happening.

Comment: For the same reason given in your previous question--"bar" doesn't exist once the class declaration has been processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things here....You have defined an instance method `instance` for `BasicObject`. You are then calling this instance method on the `Foo` object. The Foo object is a class. You have not set any instance variables for the Foo object. You set an instance variable with the `@` sign.
All that the `instance` method does is set the instance variable @ins to itself.

The `, binding` is not needed here either as `binding` is a top level method that returns the current variable bindings. You only need to save a `binding` if you need to pass around a saved "environment". Having `, binding` does not hurt anything but is redundant.

```
 BasicObject.class_eval do
    def instance(ins)
       eval "@#{ins}= @#{ins}", binding      # @ after the '='
    end
 end



class Foo
  @bar = 3     # @ here
end
Foo.instance(:bar)
puts Foo.instance_variable_get("@bar")    # Shows the instance variable @bar for Foo object
```